# Similar Users in MovieLens Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find the similar users in Movie Lens data using numpy in python so that all calculations are fast. However, I am not able to get the final code to find similarity using matrices mulplications etc.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# pass in column names for each CSV and read them using pandas. 
# Column names available in the readme file

def train_test_split(ratings):
    test = np.zeros(ratings.shape)
    train = ratings.copy()
    for user in xrange(ratings.shape[0]):
        test_ratings = np.random.choice(ratings[user, :].nonzero()[0],size=10,replace=False)
        train[user, test_ratings] = 0.
        test[user, test_ratings] = ratings[user, test_ratings]
    # Test and training are truly disjoint
    assert(np.all((train * test) == 0)) 
    return train, test
def similarity(ratings, kind='user', epsilon=1e-9):
    # epsilon -> small number for handling dived-by-zero errors
    if kind == 'user':
        sim = ratings.dot(ratings.T) + epsilon
    elif kind == 'item':
        sim = ratings.T.dot(ratings) + epsilon
    #Till here I have found the matrix which contains users multplications and squares with themselves..
    #What shall be written to return from here ??


if __name__ == '__main__':

#Reading users file:
u_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.user', sep='|', names=u_cols,
encoding='latin-1')

#Reading ratings file:
r_cols = ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', names=r_cols,
encoding='latin-1')

#Reading items file:
i_cols = ['item_id', 'movie title' ,'release date','video release date', 'IMDb URL', 'unknown', 'Action', 'Adventure',
'Animation', 'Children\'s', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Documentary', 'Drama', 'Fantasy',
'Film-Noir', 'Horror', 'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'War', 'Western']
items = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.item', sep='|', names=i_cols,
encoding='latin-1')
r_cols = ['user_id', 'item_id', 'rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings_base = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/ua.base', sep='\t', names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')
ratings_test = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/ua.test', sep='\t', names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')

n_users = ratings.user_id.unique().shape[0]
n_items = ratings.item_id.unique().shape[0]

rating_array = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for row in ratings.itertuples():
    rating_array[row[1]-1, row[2]-1] = row[3]
print rating_array
sparsity = float(len(rating_array.nonzero()[0]))
sparsity = sparsity / (rating_array.shape[0] * rating_array.shape[1])
sparsity = sparsity * 100
print 'Sparsity: {:4.2f}%'.format(sparsity)
train,test=train_test_split(rating_array)
train=train[:6][:6]
user_similarity = fast_similarity(train, kind='user')
#print user_similarity[:6][:6]
```

So any help in writing matrix calculations and its explanations will help in understanding how to solve these kind of equations.

Comment: code is taken from http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/ however I am not able to unsersatnd the fast_similarity code.. Any help here is appreciated

Comment: Is there a restriction of self implementing the code. There are various libraries, which can compute it easily. "Reinventing the wheel"